# Make label equal the return of PHP script

Tags: php, html, dns, label, echo

I have been working with some code that will check the name servers of a domain. If the name servers contain the word "inmotion", I want the label in my HTML form to say "Nameservers have been updated", else it should say "Name servers have not been updated".

The only thing I am confused about is making the label in the form say whether they have been updated.

Here is the working PHP code:

```
<?php
$b = $_REQUEST['domain'];
$dns = dns_get_record($b, DNS_NS);

$c = $dns[0]['target'];
$d = $dns[1]['target'];
if (strpos($c, 'inmotion') !== false) {
    echo 'Nameservers have been updated';

}else {
  echo "Nameservers haven't been updated";
}
?>
```

---

Here is my HTML code:

```
iframe{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
 <form action="dnscheck.php" target="my_iframe" class = "input" method="post">
     <label class = "label" for="other">Verify Domain Connection</label><br />
     <input class = "field" type="text" name="domain" /><br />
    <input type="submit"  class = "btn" name="submit" value="Verify" />
    <iframe class="iframe" name="my_iframe" src="not_submitted_yet.aspx"></iframe>
    <label name="result" id="result></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've updated your question and removed the snippet as it only supports JS.

Comment: people still use iframes? there is always a better way.

Comment: @Dagon I did not want to use the iframe, but I was unsure about calling a PHP script without leaving the page. I was reading about using AJAX, but was confused.

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe isn't cross domain, you could write javascript in your child iframe to set the value of the label in the paren't document.

Something like this

```
       <?php
            $var = "Hello World";
        ?>
    <script>
            parent.document.getElementById("myLabel").value = "<? echo $var;  ?>";
    </script>
```

If they are cross domain, your best bet would be to use the iframe as the label. Remove the label, echo the value you want to show in the label and style your iframe accordingly.